Projective geometry: implications of unicity of conic through 5 points of which no 3 collinear (no coordinates)
This is in the projective plane. In several books, Coxeter proves that 5 points of which no 3 collinear determine a unique conic, or dually, 5 lines of which no 3 concurrent determine a unique conic touching them. Lets focus on the dual. Here is how he goes about it: He proves that, given a projectivity $X \barwedge Y$ between points on two lines $p$ and $q$ that is not a perspectivity, the envelope of the lines $XY$ of the projectivity is a conic touching $p$ and $q$. Since 5 lines no 3 of which are concurrent determine a projectivity that is not a perspectivity, one immediately has a conic touching the given 5 lines. For the unicity, when $p$ and $q$ are tangent to a given conic and if $z$ is a tangent through $Z$ on $p$, $z\neq p$, and if the intersection point of $z$ and $q$ is $W$ then necessarily one has that $W$ is the image of $Z$ under a unique projectivity. Now, the unicity means that, when you are given 5 lines, no 3 of which are concurrent, the lines of all the projectivities determined by the five lines are all the same. So for instance(see figure) the projectivities $X_8X_2X_9\barwedge X_3X_4X_7$ and $X_2X_6X_4\barwedge X_8X_1X_3$ will have the same lines connecting points with their images (namely the tangents to the unique conic). But how could one prove this directly?

